# Ajuda com bootstrap responsivo

Tags: html, css3, mobile, bootstrap, layout-responsivo

Estou desenvolvendo um site com bootstrap. O site ja esta pronto para desktop, porém estou com dificuldade para deixa-lo responsivo.
No site tenho várias divs, uma embaixo da outra. Quando diminuo a tela do site, o texto da div de cima vai para div de baixo e isso vai acontecendo com todos os textos abaixo.
Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Trecho do código para telas pequenas:

```
@media screen and (max-width:550px) {
        header .info a {display:none;}
        header .info i {display:none;}
        header .info span {padding:8px;}
        footer .colunas {width:100%;height:auto;}
        .f-info form {width:95%;}
        .sessionThree {display: none;}
        .sessionTwo h1 {display: fixed;}
        .sessionTwo p {max-height: 30px;}

        label.div {width:100%;}
        button[type=submit] {width:100%;}

}
```

A primeira DIV que o texto cai para DIV de baixo:

```
.sessionTwo {
border: 2px;
border-color: black solid;
background-color: #A60D0D;
margin-top: -120px;
background-image: url(../../midia/img/3.png);
width: auto;
min-height: 700px;
background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.sessionTwo h1 {
font-size: 50px;
font-weight: normal;
font-family: Lobster;
color: white;
padding-top: 80px;
padding-left: 80px;
max-height: 150px;
max-width: 550px;
}

.sessionTwo p {
color: white;
font-weight: normal;
padding-top: 130px;
padding-left: 80px;
max-height: 170px;
max-width: 500px;
}
```

Desde ja agradeço!

Comment: Colocar trecho do código com problema, caso contrario fica impossível te ajudar

Comment: Ainda falta o html